# Azure Scheduler - Unable to assign body to HTTP POST from management portal

Tags: azure, scheduler

I am unable to assign body to a scheduler job from management portal (Action Type - HTTP & Method - POST). Once I update a job from portal, page reloads and body turns empty. Also, the job is triggering HTTP request with empty message.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I have raised a technical support ticket with Microsoft to look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Azure portal, which got resolved after I raised it with support.